# SVG Fill available space in nested elements

Tags: python, css, svg, pycairo

I am generating a SVG with nested elements. For the styling of the elements, there needs to be separate fill colours with opacity for the parent container and child elements. However, due to opacity, the colours overlap and it is not a clean result. Is there a way to fill only the space not occupied by child elements in the parent container

I am looking for an equivalent of the polygon *evenodd* fill rule but for nested elements

[image]

Comment: Instead of changing the opacity you may try to use svg `fill-opacity`either as an attribute or in css. There is also a `stroke-opacity`. If this is not solving your problem please add a working example and maybe show us the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a mask and a filter. The filter creates an image from the children, where all pixels that are not fully transparent become black and all fully transparent pixels become white. The result of the filter and a white rectangle that covers all the area that the child does not cover is then applied as a mask.

```css
#parentElement {
  fill: rgba(204, 41, 41, 0.3);
}

#childElement {
  fill: green;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<svg width=400 height=400>
  <defs>
    <filter id="mask-filter">
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="255" intercept="0"></feFuncA>
      </feComponentTransfer>      
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
          values="0 0 0 -1 1
                  0 0 0 -1 1
                  0 0 0 -1 1
                  0 0 0 0 1" />
    </filter> 
    <mask id="mask1">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
      <use xlink:href="#childElement" filter="url(#mask-filter)" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect id="parentElement" x=10 y=10 width=140 height=100 mask="url(#mask1)" />
  <rect id="childElement" x=60 y=40 width=240 height=140 />
</svg>
```